# How axios interceptor gets triggered

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-typescript

I am creating a response interceptor to get the status type and set the flag based on the status type so that an ant d modal popup can be loaded based the flag value.
How this Interceptor will be triggered for every http calls and how to set the flag in response interceptor so that i can read it in another typescript class to show modal popup

import axios, { AxiosInstance } from 'axios';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(function(response){
console.log("New Interceptor response");
console.log(response.status);
console.log(response.statusText);
return response;
},
function (error){
return Promise.reject(console.error);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the axios in a hook like useReqest or sth. set the interceptor and it will be triggered every time you use this hook. Axios like RegExp has some state in it so it remembers some settings.

Essentially you must use the axios instance which has been configured with an interceptor and will be called by default. Same thing like intercepors in Spring/NestJS/Express if you are familiar with backend dev.

Comment: Tried few things but still my interceptors are not hitting in the interceptor typescript file. Interceptors works when i give it in the existing ts file where i have the call to api. How can i make it trigger in new tsx file

export const getCurrentUser = async () => {
  const response = await axios.get<UserData>('/api/users/current');
  return response.data;
};

Comment: every time you import axios in a file you must set up the interceptor because it is ultimately different instance, that's why I told you to create a reusable wrapper which you can reuse throughout your app e.g. you only define axios once in a file and set the interceptor